# Downsampling with Nvidia or in general

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, games

is it possible to Downsample Games?
(in Windows its possible via Gedosato or the Graphics drivers)
I would like to play games in 4k+ on Linux.
My System: Ubuntu 16 and Nvidia 970 with latest drivers.

Greetings